# converting ascii to sac using python

Tags: python, ascii

I'm trying to convert an ASCII file to a sac file format using python.
What I did is reading the ASCII file and converting it to an array float using numpy.

After defining the headers, I saved the Array of float in the Sac format.
When opening the so generated Sac file with `./sac` and printing the headers, parts of the header, i.e. the coordinates of the events and of the stations are not listed.

Apparently, I did something wrong when defining the header, but I have no idea how to define the header in another way... So I'd be very glad if someone has any idea or tip!

Thanks in advance! :)

Here's what I did:

```
import numpy as np
from obspy import UTCDateTime, read, Trace, Stream
import pandas as pd
import os

x = pd.read_csv('Test', header=1, na_values='-')
x1 = x.to_numpy()
stats = {
    'network': 'B',
    'station': 'XXX',
    'channel': 'Z',
    'npts': len(x1),
    'sampling_rate': 50,
    'delta': '0.02',
    'b': '0',
    'stla': 87.0000,
    'stlo': 2.000,
    'evla': 16.000,
    'evlo': 7.000,
    'nzyear': '2017',
    'nzjday': '001',
    'nzhour': '00',
    'nzmin': '00',
    'nzsec': '00',
    'nzmsec':'000',
    'mseed': {'dataquality': 'D'}
} 
stats['starttime']= '2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z'
x2 = x1[0:].reshape((len(x1),))

st = Stream([Trace(data=x2, header=stats)])
st.write("Test.sac", format='SAC')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help to solve the problem:

https://lists.swapbytes.de/archives/obspy-users/2015-November/001901.html

in other words, as a quick correction if you write your code this way:

```
import numpy as np
from obspy import UTCDateTime, read, Trace, Stream
import pandas as pd
import os

x = pd.read_csv('Test', header=1, na_values='-')
x1 = x.to_numpy()
stats = {
    'network': 'B',
    'station': 'XXX',
    'channel': 'Z',
    'npts': len(x1),
    'sampling_rate': 50,
    'delta': '0.02',
    'b': '0',
    'stla': 87.0000,
    'stlo': 2.000,
    'evla': 16.000,
    'evlo': 7.000,
    'nzyear': '2017',
    'nzjday': '001',
    'nzhour': '00',
    'nzmin': '00',
    'nzsec': '00',
    'nzmsec':'000',
    'mseed': {'dataquality': 'D'}
} 
stats['starttime']= '2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z'
x2 = x1[0:].reshape((len(x1),))
st = Stream([Trace(data=x2, header=stats)])


for tr in st:
    tr.stats.sac = obspy_to_sac_header(tr.stats)
    tr.stats.sac.stla = 87.0000
    tr.stats.sac.stlo = 2.000
    
tr.write("Test.sac", format='SAC')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverfow, BitaNajd! It's best to answer questions with more than just a link. What exactly at that link are you referencing? What wasn't working in the OP's code, and what did you change to make it work?